# How set an OnClickListener by not extending ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, android-event

How am I to set an `OnItemClickListener` event for a `Listview` if I'm not extending `ListActivity` class?

Can someone provide me with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have a list view in the activity that you are using....

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View view,
        int position,
                    long id) {
                    // Whatever you want to do.
    }
});
```

Is that what you are looking for?